# PFLoginViewController and Facebook Login: couldn't login

Tags: objective-c, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I'm currently experiencing a problem with the PFLoginViewController and Facebook Login process. I set up the FB app from the developer page, I put the APP id e secret ID in the Parse App setting in the Authorization tab then I add a URL scheme and FacebookAppID e DisplayName as string in the Custom iOS Target. All the required Frameworks have been previously installed in the app. When I click the Facebook login button the error I get is the following:

```
    014-09-26 00:52:31.865 Diary[17009:19a03] -[__NSArrayI rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa3545b0
2014-09-26 00:52:31.902 Diary[17009:19a03] CRASH: -[__NSArrayI rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa3545b0
2014-09-26 00:52:31.911 Diary[17009:19a03] Stack Trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0260e02e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f6fe7e objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x026994bd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 253
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x025fdbbc ___forwarding___ + 588
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x025fd94e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Diary                               0x00094f9c -[PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider containsPublishPermission] + 202
    6   Diary                               0x00095203 -[PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider authenticateWithSuccess:failure:cancel:] + 497
    7   Diary                               0x00030e36 +[PFUser(Private) logInWithProvider:block:] + 249
    8   Diary                               0x0003246a +[PFUser(Private) logInWithAuthType:block:] + 129
    9   Diary                               0x00093bca +[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:block:] + 177
    10  Diary                               0x0005ef45 -[PFLogInViewController logInUsingFacebook] + 193
    11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f83705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    12  UIKit                               0x00eb72c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    13  UIKit                               0x00eb7258 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    14  UIKit                               0x00f78021 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    15  UIKit                               0x00f7857f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
    16  UIKit                               0x00f776e8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
    17  UIKit                               0x00ee6cef -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
    18  UIKit                               0x00ee6f02 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    19  UIKit                               0x00ec4d4a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    20  UIKit                               0x00eb6698 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x021ecdf9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x021ecad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x02583bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x02583962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x025b4bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x025b3f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x025b3e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x021eb7e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x021eb668 GSEventRun + 104
    30  UIKit                               0x00eb3ffc UIApplicationMain + 1211
    31  Diary                               0x0000225d main + 141
    32  Diary                               0x00002185 start + 53
)
2014-09-26 00:52:31.912 Diary[17009:19a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa3545b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x260e012 0x1f6fe7e 0x26994bd 0x25fdbbc 0x25fd94e 0x94f9c 0x95203 0x30e36 0x3246a 0x93bca 0x5ef45 0x1f83705 0xeb72c0 0xeb7258 0xf78021 0xf7857f 0xf776e8 0xee6cef 0xee6f02 0xec4d4a 0xeb6698 0x21ecdf9 0x21ecad0 0x2583bf5 0x2583962 0x25b4bb6 0x25b3f44 0x25b3e1b 0x21eb7e3 0x21eb668 0xeb3ffc 0x225d 0x2185)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Any suggestion?